# Android Studio debugger does not stop at breakpoint inside onItemClick() ?

Tags: android, listview

> Toast message is seen but breakpoint does not stop execution. 
>   The following method is inside onCreate of NewsListActivity..

```
// click event for list item
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int myPostion = position;
            long myID = id;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewsListActivity.this,NewsDetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: mark brakpoint to specific line in onclicklistion and debuging time presss contr+f9 key.

Comment: Thanks @Vasant.  i tried but still not working. :(

Comment: Have you tried the breakpoint on different lines of that method?  Are you starting with "Debug" (not "Run")?